# Sort multiple array of objects in Mongo Aggregation

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Ashwanth Madhav",
    "scores" : [
            {
                    "type" : "exam",
                    "score" : 45
            },
            {
                    "type" : "quiz",
                    "score" : 34
            },
            {
                    "type" : "work",
                    "score" : 99
            },
            {
                    "type" : "work",
                    "score" : 38
            }
    ],
  "job_type" : [
            {
                    "type" : "full_time",
                    "activity" :87
            },
            {
                    "type" : "part_time",
                    "activity" : 78
            },
            {
                    "type" : "full_time",
                    "activity" : 71.76133439165544
            }
    ]
}
```

When using `$addToSet` the sorted list is getting unsorted. So I used `$push`. But it leads to duplication of data.

I need to get SCORES and JOB_TYPE sorted. Now, I have done it with, Used `$addToSet` first, then "`$unwind`" score-> "`$sort`" -> "`$group`" with `$push`. After "`$unwind`" job type -> "`$sort`" -> "`$group`" it with `$push`.

Is there any better way? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried first adding it to the set through `$addToSet` and then sorting with a `$push` command? OR depending on your use-case, you can sort after a query… but that doesn't answer your actual question.

Comment: @ThomasHesse
I already done with this way.  `$addToSet` -> `$unwind` -> `$sort` -> `$push'

I have not only the scores and job_type field. Its dummy fields. 5 `$lookup` s with `$limit` and `$skip`. So these all 5 arrays need to be an a sorted order. So here I user `$addToSet` then then `$push` for each array. But I think this is not the correct way.

Comment: FIXED.
When doing $lookup , I tried $unwind and $group inside the pipeline stage and work fine.